# how to identify which process occupying more cache in linux server

Tags: linux, memory, cache

We have Linux test server of 12 GB RAM, 6-7 GB of which is buff/cache. How to identify which process is having more cache. The test server has tomcat servers running on it which we have set max usable memory to 128 mb and also some database like postgress and db2 running which accumulating 4GB used memory but its  hard to understand how it is taking to 7GB in Cache. Is there any way to find it?

Comment: AFAIK cache isn’t associated with a process. Cached files aren’t opened ATM. ***However***  it appears you’re confused about what cache is. It is *not* “used” memory. It well be freed when required. Having RAM idling around holding nothing is wasteful, hence cache.

Comment: Sorry my question might be little confusing. here is snapshot of memory usuage. KiB Mem : 12140304 total,  1253404 free,  5618428 used,  5268472 buff/cache. its around 5GB in used and another 5GB in cache wanted to understand how i can free the 5GB and put into use. can it be done?

Comment: You can put it to use *right now*. It will *automatically* be freed as applications demand more memory. // Instead of slapping some numbers in a comment, edit your question and add the complete output of `free -m`, in a [code block](http://superuser.com/editing-help#code).